# Transform log table into another table with values spread over every month

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging, timestamp

I have a table with rows consisting of values and timestamps. A row is inserted whenever the value has changed, and the timestamp indicates when the change has happened. For example, something like this:

```
 id  | value |         timestamp          
-----+-------+----------------------------
   1 |   736 | 2014-03-18 16:38:22.20548
   2 |   531 | 2014-06-18 16:38:22.664324
   3 |    24 | 2014-07-18 16:38:22.980137
   4 |   530 | 2014-09-22 10:01:36.13856
   5 |   529 | 2014-09-23 10:01:27.202026
```

I need a query in Postgresql which generates a table with one row for every month of the year. Every row has a timestamp (first day of the month) and a value. The value is the last value of the first table which was inserted before the beginning of the given month. The value should be 0 if there are no matching rows in the first table. Something like this:

```
 id  | value |         timestamp          
-----+-------+----------------------------
   1 |     0 | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000000
   2 |     0 | 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000
   3 |     0 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00.000000
   4 |   736 | 2014-04-01 00:00:00.000000
   5 |   736 | 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000000
   6 |   736 | 2014-06-01 00:00:00.000000
   7 |   531 | 2014-07-01 00:00:00.000000
   8 |    24 | 2014-08-01 00:00:00.000000
   9 |    24 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00.000000
  10 |   529 | 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000000
  11 |   529 | 2014-11-01 00:00:00.000000
  12 |   529 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00.000000
```

I tried for a while, but I didn't manage to get the full result. I guess I need to generate a list of months like this.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  generate_series('2014-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, now(), '1 month') AS months
```

And then do something like this to get the last occurrency before a month:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM first_table
WHERE timestamp < --current_month_selection--
ORDER BY timestamp desc 
LIMIT 1;
```

I guess one needs an OUTER JOIN and a CASE conditional...
Unfortunately I didn't manage to put it all together. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I solved this by myself, it was quite trivial:

```
SELECT 
  month,
  COALESCE((SELECT value 
  FROM first_table
  WHERE timestamp < month
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 1),0)
FROM 
  generate_series('2014-01-01 00:00'::timestamp, now(), '1 month') AS month
```